# $(...).epoch is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, epoch.js

I am trying to run a basic example from the website http://epochjs.github.io/epoch/real-time and I get the following error

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).epoch is not a function TypeError: $(...).epoch is not a function
```

here is my index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/epoch.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/epoch.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="areaChart" style="width: 800px; height: 200px"></div>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var areaChartData = [
          {
            label: "Layer 1",
            values: [ {x: 0, y: 100}, {x: 20, y: 1000} ]
          },
          {
            label: "Layer 2",
            values: [ {x: 0, y: 78}, {x: 20, y: 98}]
          }];
        $('#areaChart').epoch({
          type: 'area',
          data: areaChartData
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

epoch seem to use d3.time which doesn't exist in d3.v4 so switching it to d3.v3 fixes the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```